# asp css with simple float not working on treeview

Tags: html, css, asp.net, treeview

My goal is to make a `treeview` in left and `content place holder` in its right. This is the `HTML` :

```
<body>
    <form id="formMenu" runat="server">
    <asp:TreeView ID="treeMenu" runat="server" DataSourceID="SiteMapDataSource1">
    </asp:TreeView>

    <asp:SiteMapDataSource ID="SiteMapDataSource1" runat="server" />

    <div id="content">
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">

        </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

And this is my `CSS` :

```
#treeMenu
{
    float:left;
    width:200px;
}

#content
{
    float:right;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
}
```

The float is working prematurely. The `#content` floated to the right of `#treeMenu`, but its floated too right and its position is **below** the `#treeMenu` instead just at the right of it.

I tried to use `overflow:hidden` but its not giving any effect.

Please kindly help me. Thanks for your help.

Comment: As an example of floating both elements to the left check this fiddle out https://jsfiddle.net/gno0se5o/

Comment: @Kinburn101 Thanks a lot. I tried to follow your fiddle, i even make sure the width and height is same but in my case the content always go to below the tree. I checked your HTML and it should be same like mine. This is confusing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I need to wrap the `TreeView` with a `div` and use the `div`'s `id` to do the `CSS` to make it work.

Answer (score 2):

You could add `overflow:auto` to `#content`, do not set any `float` on it.

```css
#menubar {
    float:left;
    width:200px;
    background:lime;
}
#content {
    overflow:auto;
    background:orange;
}
```

```html
<div id="menubar">menubar</div>
<div id="content">Chocolate liquorice gummi bears biscuit macaroon cheesecake candy sugar plum. Liquorice sugar plum caramels cookie candy toffee pie. Bonbon pudding cotton candy. Soufflé bear claw sesame snaps soufflé pudding chupa chups pudding ice cream candy. Marshmallow carrot cake muffin apple pie powder. Tootsie roll cotton candy cheesecake. Dragée candy canes toffee. Dragée toffee macaroon. Ice cream gummies chocolate sugar plum. Oat cake danish powder cake sugar plum biscuit. Gummi bears liquorice jelly beans. Chocolate bar biscuit gummi bears pastry chocolate cake marzipan cake.</div>
```

Or, you could set use `table-cell` for both elements.

```css
#menubar {
    display:table-cell;
    width:200px;
    background:lime;
}
#content {
    display:table-cell;
    background:orange;
}
```

```html
<div id="menubar">menubar</div>
<div id="content">Chocolate liquorice gummi bears biscuit macaroon cheesecake candy sugar plum. Liquorice sugar plum caramels cookie candy toffee pie. Bonbon pudding cotton candy. Soufflé bear claw sesame snaps soufflé pudding chupa chups pudding ice cream candy. Marshmallow carrot cake muffin apple pie powder. Tootsie roll cotton candy cheesecake. Dragée candy canes toffee. Dragée toffee macaroon. Ice cream gummies chocolate sugar plum. Oat cake danish powder cake sugar plum biscuit. Gummi bears liquorice jelly beans. Chocolate bar biscuit gummi bears pastry chocolate cake marzipan cake.</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, but none of them is working in my case. The 2nd option make the content just below the tree, while the 1st still make the content below the tree but with smaller width (i assume because of `float:left`). I think the problem is because the ASP i used, not a normal HTML. Please kindly take a look at my ASP markup if you have time.

Comment: @BlazeTama I think it's probably like this - http://jsfiddle.net/z053hrr5/, just to confirm.

Comment: Yes, it looks like that. I tried to add width and height for both of the elements but its still not working.

Comment: Unfortunately, i cant. I use visual studio 2008. Could you kindly explain to me why this happened? What should i do?

Comment: @BlazeTama I updated the answer above, have made my best without see the actually html code.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, i figured out a solution. All i need is a div wrapper for the tree. An hour for this.